# Querying data created N days from now without additional package

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

How to query data created N days from now without additional package..??

I have researched this question and all answer use additional package.

info: 
Date store with ISODate: new Date()

thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find by date using (in MongoShell):

```
"date_of_story" : { $gte: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 3) }
```

Or, in Javascript:

```
"date_of_story" : { $gte: new Date(new Date().getTime() - 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 3) }
```

Where `3` is the number of days you want to go back.

Comment: Note: 3600 * 24 could be calculated to make it shorter, but I like to keep it as it is, so I remember it's 3600 seconds by 24 hours.

Comment: hello @ConstantinGuay thanks for taking your time... however i got `ReferenceError: ISODate is not defined` have a clue what's going on..?? thank You,,

Comment: Ha yes sure, this would work in Mongo Shell. For Javascript, just use a `Date` object: `new Date(new Date().getTime() - 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 3)` (I update my answer according that).

Comment: yayy...this is great,,!! just 1 line of code,, and new learning experiece..thank You so much..yes this is for meteor, maybe i should clarify the title..thanks again